# Reload an HTML page just once using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

How can I reload an HTML base web page only once? I am using `history.go(0);` with function `onLoad` in body tag but i want to run it only once. Please keep in mind that I am using `iframe` so this is not possible to to use the below types code:

```
<script language=" JavaScript" ><!--
function MyReload()
{
window.location.reload();
}
//--></script>

<Body onLoad=" MyReload()" >
```

The above code did not work for me.

However the code below is working well but the problem is that I need it to load only once:

```
<BODY BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF background="../images/Index_04.jpg" onLoad="history.go(0)" >
```

Note: I am using two iframes when user click on main page link a page loads in iframe then I want to reload the whole page with current iframe page.

Comment: Why the BOLD TAGS, the nineties are long gone

Comment: you are tryin to reload everytime it loads, why are you trying to reload in the first way, maybe there is  better alternative

Comment: This doesn't make any sense whatsoever, as soon as the page loads, it would reload and be a new page so it would reload again (for the first time for that load). I *guess* you are trying to get the browser to show the most recent content, that is done with [cache control](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to do that, so that our suggestions will be more in-context?

Comment: @lbu @Quentin read my question i need it loads once because i am using iframe when user click on link it loads a iframe than i want to load the whole with the same which he opens recently

Comment: Ok you will need to take a completly different approach because reloading does not do that. if you want to load a different page in your iframe when the user click on something, use javascript. tis the best way

Comment: @Danish - having re-read what you're trying to achieve - this is not going to work. I'd highly recommend a different approach.

You could perhaps looks at reloading just the portions of the containing page that need to be reloaded ... as you're not comfortable with JavaScript you'd probably be safer looking at JQuery... or alternatively a good book (JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `querystring` at the end of the page url (e.g. ?r), and check for it before redirecting, as if it exists, the redirect is already done.

```
if(window.location.href.substr(-2) !== "?r") {
  window.location = window.location.href + "?r";
}
```

Disclaimer: I agree with others that you probably have a better solution - and should never need to refresh 'just once'.

**Explanation of use**

At the bottom of your page, just above the `</body>` you should put this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(window.location.href.substr(-2) !== "?r") {
      window.location = window.location.href + "?r";
    }
</script>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //Check if the current URL contains '#' 
            if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1)
            {
                // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
                url = document.URL+"#";
                location = "#";

                //Reload the page
                location.reload(true);

            }
        });
    </script>
```

Due to the if condition the page will reload only once. Hope this will help.

Comment: this works - but it appends a # to the URL - not ideal. This also effects the browser 'back' button because it goes back to the non-url appended page. How can you refresh the page once on load - without appending the URL?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution which works for me using localStorage. In this solution we don't need to modify existing url.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 (function()
 {
  if( window.localStorage ){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('firstReLoad')){
     localStorage['firstReLoad'] = true;
     window.location.reload();
    } else {
     localStorage.removeItem('firstReLoad');
    }
  }
 })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this is by using cookies (or if your on the right platform, sessions) and flag the first time it has reloaded, variables might also work in this case, because we're speaking about IFRAME, but I have never tried such thing.