# how to reload page using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to refresh a page using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294842/how-to-refresh-a-page-using-javascript)

how to reload (refresh) the web-page through java script only once not repeatedly. I want to refresh the page once at a time.

Comment: That's a very good question for [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=how+to+reload+page+using+javascrip).

Comment: please guys read the question carefully and concentrate on "once and not repeatedly" word. ok?

Comment: Then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160415/reload-an-html-page-just-once-using-javascript

Comment: It looks like nobody read the "once" - if you want that, use `if(location.search !== "?norefresh") location.href += "?norefresh"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh (reload) the page you can use `location.reload(true)`.
This link may help you to explore it further more [Javascript Refresh Page](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

using `history.go(0)` refreshes the current page

Comment: this is not useful in my case it will refreshing every 1 seconds. I need only once.

Comment: It will refresh only once. If your page refreshes multiple times, the cause must be elsewhere in your code. Review your question and give us some example code, i'd say.

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload( true );`

The parameter tells the browser, to always reload the current page from the server. If that is skipped or explicitly set to `false`, the browser may load the page from its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Options :-

```
window.location.reload()
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you

```
window.location.reload(true);
```