# I want to make the page refresh onto a different url but only once

Tags: html

I need to make the page automatically refresh after 5 seconds onto a slightly different url so instead of /index.html I want it to be /index.html#h

this keeps refreshing it, I was wondering if there are any alternatives that will only do it once

Comment: Do you have some code from your current attempt, so we have a better idea of your approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload an HTML page just once using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160415/reload-an-html-page-just-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Javascript, [you can check for a certain cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), then not refresh if the cookie is present. If there's no cookie, then refresh and set the cookie.